# How to get rid of zombie processes after using EA's Java Automation interface?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am building an application that connects to Enterprise Architect using the Java automation interface.  When the program exits, an EA process remains in the Windows Task Manager.

The application is using `windowClosing` hooks to call `.CloseFile()`, `.Exit()`, and `.destroy()` on the repository object, but the EA process remains.  Adding a call to force garbage collection does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: `COM Automation` implements sort-of reference counting garbage collector. When the number of references to a COM-exposed object drops to 0, the object can be removed/closed. When number of references to all COM-exposed objects owned by a COM-server drop to 0  then the COM-server itself can be removed/closed. The fact that EA keeps running in the background indicates some reference-counting  problem on your side. See [MSDN: Rules for Managing Reference Counts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692481(v=vs.85).aspx) for some more details

Comment: This might be part of the problem.  I think I finally figured it out, but have not worked out the solution.  I have written two applications using the automation interface - both fail to close EA, but one of them gets much farther.  That's because it does all of the work in the thread before returning.

Comment: If you add code that replicates the problem to your question ([mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) then someone may spot what's wrong

Comment: @xmojmr Thank you, I found the problem, I just haven't had the opportunity to document that solution in a meaningful way for this community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading an EA file can take quite a long time.  During this time, there is nothing the user can do but wait...so the application displays a "Please Wait" screen.  In order to keep the UI from freezing, all of the loading is done in a separate thread (not a SwingWorker) while a loading animation is played on the Glass Pane.

The automation interface uses COM and when the loader thread dies, it trashes the COM connection.  All of the data gathered prior to the thread ending was fine, but all subsequent accesses failed (somewhat mysteriously).  Since the connection was severed, the application could not disconnect from EA (hence the zombies).

I solved the problem by getting a reference to the EA Repository object on the main thread (a very quick operation) but still deferred loading to the worker thread.  Since the main thread stays alive throughout the life of the application, the COM connection stays alive and the interface works as it was originally expected to.